# Ugly whitespace in help center two column layout

Tags: feature-request, design, help-center

When I view the help center main page, I see a two column layout with lots of unnecessary white space. This happens on SO, Meta, and SU, but it does not happen on Programmers, DBAs, or Skeptics. The latter three appear to have smaller fonts and tighter layouts. Both groups include sites where I do and don't have accounts.

This is how it looks with two columns:

[image: It's mad because I called it ugly]

There's a similar blank spot below the badges / privileges section. The layout could be improved by realigning the rows:

[image: I hate scrolling]

I assume the layout is being generated based on available screen space. Or perhaps it's table row overflow? I'm set at 1280x1024 (that's as big as it gets), and running vanilla Chrome 27.0.1453.110 m on Windows XP. I use a 125% global zoom, but reducing it back to 100% and force refreshing doesn't fix the issue. I am stricken with a severe case of resolution envy. I've checked with IE 8 as well, both zoomed and not, and I see the three column layout there, which renders nicely.

**I'm well aware that most people see a three column layout. As indicated above, I do in some places as well, and it looks nice. This question is *not* "why don't I see three columns", it's "please make this look better for people with crappy screens". Try cranking your resolution down and clearing your cache if you want to attempt reproducing it.**

Comment: +1 for the schema. But can't repro here. FireFox 21.0

Comment: I count 3 columns on my screen.

Comment: It shows 3 columns unless I zoom out to 35% or less.

Comment: I'm running the same Chrome version on Windows 7 and don't see this either. I see the same as hjpotter92...

Comment: @hjpotter92, ben, Richard - you're missing the point. "I see three columns" adds nothing to the discussion. If you can get it to show two columns, do you see the white space as indicated?

Comment: 1000px is the minimum width we support, but I can't get this to reproduce. That's not to say it _won't_ reproduce, I'm just not seeing any love when I try it. I'll make a note to point this out tomorrow if it hasn't yet been seen.